# Creating Annotations in Java like Mockito's before

Tags: java, annotations, processing

In processing I have several functions that change the properties of applet to draw stuff, for instance:

```
public void resetBackground(PApplet pApplet){
pApplet.fill(175);
pApplet.noStroke();
pApplet.rect(0,0,100,100);
}
```

But I want these functions to preserve the state of the pApplet after the function call, for that I have something like:

```
public void resetBackground(PApplet pApplet){
SaveAndRestoreDefaults saveAndRestoreDefaults = new SaveAndRestoreDefaults(pApplet);
// Code that changes state.
saveAndRestoreDefaults.restoreOriginals();
}
```

Now this works for me but I would like this not to clutter my code here but rather be annotation driven, something like:

```
@PreserveState
public void resetBackground(){
// code that changes state.
}
```

I have done a little research on it but it seems to be not an easy task. The googling took me to AOP and I don't want to spend time to learn that. Is there an easier way to achieve the same?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend staying in Processing, instead of reaching into the underlying virtual machine API (just because you run it in java, doesn't mean every implementation of Processing has a JVM. Processing.js comes to mind).

Just make a state class and keep track that way:

```
class SketchState {
  color background_color, stroke_color, fill_color;
  SketchState(color bg, color st, color fl) {
    sketch = s; background_color = bg; stroke_color = st; fill_color = fl;
  }
}

ArrayList<SketchState> stateCache = new ArrayList<SketchState>();

void cacheState() {
  stateCache.add(new SketchState(...));
}

void restoreState() {
  SketchState rest = stateCache.remove(stateCache.size()-1);
  background(rest.background_color);
  stroke(rest.stroke_color);
  fill(rest.fill_color);
}
```

and add whatever other state aspects you want saved to that class.

Comment: Although this is a very good strategy for saving states, but as of now I do not care about other implementations of processing and will like to explore the annotative driven way. But thanks for this suggestion :)

Comment: especially if you don't care about other implementations, don't drop out of Processing to "whatever it runs on". Processing isn't java, it's a programming model that's different form java, with an api that only derives from java. So this is the solution I'd always give you; it's just a bonus that now your code'll work on non-JVM versions of Processing.